# getting description of bigquery table

Tags: scala, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the description of a bq table using the following:

```
val bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()
val table = bigquery.getTable(tableId)
tableDescription = table.getDescription()
```

what I am thinking of what if not description is provided to the table I am trying to get the description from? It's written in the documenation that `getDescription` returns `string`, but what if there is no descprition provided? will it return `null`? and if yes, how do I avoid this using an `option` for example or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation indicates that the method has the signature:

```java
public String getDescription()
```

It's reasonable to assume that it might return `null` since we're dealing with a Java library. You can handle this safely by wrapping the expression as an `Option`:

```
tableDescription: Option[String] = Option(table.getDescription())
```